# conky: how to show the top internet using processes and their speeds like nethogs

Tags: conky

In Linux, I find `nethogs -a` very useful for checking the internet speed usage per program.

Now, I want to integrate this functionality into Conky.

I'm open to any other method besides nethogs, as long as I can monitor internet usage.